# Prepare Unity without showing UnityPlayer

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm integrating Unity as a subview in a native Android app.

I'd need to prepare Unity when the app starts, but without showing it, because I need to change between scenes when the user taps a button, without showing the Unity screen presentation.

The flow is:

User chooses a scene in Activity A -> Display scene in PlayGameActivity with `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage`, without Unity splash/loading screen

In iOS I did it like this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var currentUnityController: UnityAppController!

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.currentUnityController = UnityAppController()

    self.currentUnityController.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}
```

But I don't find something similar in Android.

This is how I'm showing the UnityPlayer in a subview:

```
public class PlayGameActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "PlayGameActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);

        // Create the UnityPlayer
        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
        int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
        boolean trueColor8888 = false;
        mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

        // Add the Unity view
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_unity_play_game_activity);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
        layout.addView(mUnityPlayer.getView(), 0, lp);

        String unityScene = "some_scene";
        Log.d(TAG, "calling scene " + unityScene);
        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("AController", "AMethodToChangeScene", unityScene);
    }
}
```

I tried changing scene in an Activity with the player and the buttons below, and it works, because I wait for the player to be ready. Unity does receive the message of changing scene and does so after loading itself.

So is there a way to init Unity without showing it like in iOS? Or a way to know when the UnityPlayer is ready/isn't showing the splash screen?

Answer (score 2):

I tested an approach that I think may work for you.

First I made a two View variables so that the views can be manipulated throughout the class.

```
public class PlayGameActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "PlayGameActivity";
    private View playerView;
    private RelativeLayout layout;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);

        // Create the UnityPlayer
        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
        int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
        boolean trueColor8888 = false;
        mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);
        //MODIFIED VERSION OF YOUR CODE
        playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();

        // Add the Unity view SLIGHTY MODIFIED
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_unity_play_game_activity);
        lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
        String unityScene = "some_scene";
        Log.d(TAG, "calling scene " + unityScene);
        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("AController", "AMethodToChangeScene", unityScene);
    }
}
```

Then in my test, I had two buttons with listeners set up. The first button let me send a message to Unity,

```
Button theButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        theButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mUnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("CallThis", "MessageFromAndroid", "HI!");
            }
        });
```

Then the second button did the following,

```
Button good = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        good.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            layout.addView(playerView);
            mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

So the basic idea is don't add mUnityPlayer using `layout.addView()` to the view until you are ready. You could have your program call UnitySendMessage, and then from within Unity make a call into Android that runs the second line from the button I made. That is, just replace that button I used with a function that Unity can call. You're probably familiar with it already but I'll link to the [Android Scripting API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.Call.html) anyway.

EDIT: I ran another test and it is not necessary to put mUnityPlayer.requestFocus() in the method that adds the UnityPlayer to your view.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Make Unity call Android when it's ready would is a good idea, but I don't have access to the unity code and the client is really interested in make it look as in iOS (without lag or anything).

Comment: Are you wanting to initialize mUnityPlayer in one activity, but then wait to display in a different activity?

Comment: The goal is to make PlayGameActivity (the second activity) display the game as soon as it becomes visible. I managed to do this in iOS because I could initialize Unity without showing it, but in Android I haven't been able to successfully initialize the UnityPlayer outside the Activity that will display it. The UnityPlayer initialization takes 5 sec to display the scene but I need it instantly like in iOS.

Comment: I am really intrigued by this question and not finding a solution yet. In your iOS version, it doesn't display the splash screen or anything else, just the launched scene ready to go?

Comment: Yes. In iOS I don't see Unity splash screen because I load Unity once the app starts, and since the user can't go that fast to the Unity screen, he never sees the splash screen. Also Unity is loaded once, so in subsequent calls, there isn't a chance to see the splash screen.

Comment: @RominaV I have the exact same issue, did you find a solution ?

Comment: @DavidSeroussi No... apparently there's no way to do it. But if you find a workaround, post the answer!